# "From case D to C" or "from cases D to C"

Tags: grammatical-number

I am checking the galley proofs of a scientific paper we submitted, and the copy-editor changed

> In the transition from case D to C, ...

to

> In the transition from case**s** D to C, ...

Why is this preferred?

More context, for those interested:

> Looking at the proof for the upper bound in Section 5 (specifically,
>   the second case in Figure 13b), we observe that in the transition *from case D to C*, there is 2 · |as| of unused potential. Since we are trying to show ...

Comment: On the face of it you are correct. However you haven't given us much context.  Could you give the prior sentence  and this one in full? Thanks.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the transition from case D to C

I agree with you. Case D is a single case. The sentence is a contraction of:

*"... the transition from case D to case C ..."*

If it had been,  *"...the transition from case[s] D and C ..."* then the editor would have been justified.

I suggest you go back and query the reasoning.

**Edit**

I think I can see where the copy-editor's mistake has come from.  If the phrase had been for example, "In the transition from cases C to E ...", it could have been read as, "In the transition from cases C to E inclusive ..."

The editor simply has not understood the logic of what you are saying.

Comment: Thank you! I was really wondering about this change, but the reason in your edit makes a lot of sense.